# Detach from Firestore listener

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore together with Swift.

I have a singleton data class UserManager. I call this from my different ViewControllers to get data to populate my tableviews. I want the tableviews to automatically update when the collections are updated so I need to use a SnapshotListener. Everything works fine but I'm not sure how to detach from the listener when the Viewcontroller is closed.

In the singleton class I have methods like this below. The method gives a list of users and will be called from several different places around my app.

I also want to give back a reference to the listener so that I can detach from it when the Viewcontroller is closed. But I can't get it working. The below solution gives compiler error.

I've been trying to look at the reference, for example here 
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen but I need to get it working when the data is loaded in a singleton class instead of directly in the Viewcontroller. What is the way to go here?

In UserManager:

```
func allUsers(completion:@escaping ([User], ListenerRegistration?)->Void) {
    let listener = db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        if let documents = querySnapshot?.documents {
            var users = [User]()
            for document in documents {
                let user = User(snapshot: document)
                users.append(user)
            }
            completion(users, listener)
        }
    }
}
```

In ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserManager.shared.allUsers(completion: { (users, listener) in
        self.users = users
        self.listener = listener
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

deinit {
    self.listener.remove()
}
```

Comment: Can you post your compiler error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I **guess** the compiler error that you see is referring to the fact that you are using `listener` into it's own defining context.

Try this for a change:

In UserManager:

```
func allUsers(completion:@escaping ([User])->Void) -> ListenerRegistration? {
    return db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        if let documents = querySnapshot?.documents {
            var users = [User]()
            for document in documents {
                let user = User(snapshot: document)
                users.append(user)
            }
            completion(users)
        }
    }
}
```

In ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.listener = UserManager.shared.allUsers(completion: { (users) in
        self.users = users
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

deinit {
    self.listener.remove()
}
```

Comment: Just what I needed to fix the same issue I was having. For a while I thought maybe I had a rouge viewController that was getting duplicated in my navigationController stack or something. For my application, it plays a short beep when the listener detects changes, so it was pretty apparent something was going on with multiple beeps at once lol.  THANK YOU!

Comment: I was stuck on the type for "ListenerRegistration" so this helped. Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

I think that *getDocument* instead of *addSnapshotListener* is what you are looking for.
Using this method the listener is automatically detached at the end of the request...
It will be something similar to

```
 func allUsers(completion:@escaping ([User])->Void) {
 db.collection("users").getDocument { querySnapshot, error in
     if let documents = querySnapshot?.documents {
         var users = [User]()
         for document in documents {
             let user = User(snapshot: document)
             users.append(user)
         }
         completion(users)
     }
 } }
```

Comment: Thanks! But I need to use a addSnapshotListener as I want the tableviews to automatically update when the collections are updated. The problem I'm having is to return the listener to the viewcontroller so that I can later remove it. I updated my question with some more details